# Match tags with regular expression and strip them off in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to display blog excerpts as result of a search by tag. It would not be ideal at all having `img` or `blockquote` tags in those brief paragraphs, so I would like them to be stripped off, along with their content.

In order to do this my idea is to match with a regular expression the tags and then replace them with the empty string. So here it is my code:

```
protected static String removeTags(String s)
    {
        String reg = "<img .*>";
        String excerpt = s.replace(reg, "");
        System.out.println(excerpt);
        return excerpt;
    }
```

the code seems to work very well if in the regular expression do not appear symbols like `*`, `<`, `>`: in fact if my regular expression is merely `img` the code does its job just fine and it is taken off. I've tried to use equivalent patters such as `\\w` and others but still it seems they won't match the code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just FYI: you really don't want to [use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not). Use a parser instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use regex in your match, you need to use [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead of [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Also, you probably don't want to use `.*`, since `*` is a *greedy quantifier* and will consume everything up to the last `>` in your data. Try `.*?` *(reluctant quantifier)* or `[^>]*` instead.